# Accessing On-line SharePoint list contents from external HTML or ASPX?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, sharepoint-rest-api

I'm needing to captures certain columns of an Online SharePoint list and display this data within a regular external HTML style page or aspx page, not an embedded in SharePoint. Need this on the client side without requiring SharePoint admin rights. Not sure which if any of these would get the job done; ajax, aspx, jscript, REST api or some other recommendation? With Google search found lots of Power Apps, Power Autmoate and embedded Web Part examples. But consumers of data want to included on their already running website. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.  Added;  I beleive I found some possible jscript, aspx and REST solutions on this site.  But what would be the BEST method? I know that could be a subjective question.

Comment: How are you planning to authenticate to SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

it is possible, the best way to do in JS is to use MS libraries:

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js#readme

and PNP-JS library:

https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/

https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/concepts/auth-browser/

Good luck